# How to store the value of a API response in a state?

Tags: reactjs

I want to store the value obtained after the api call in the state so that it can be rendered later on.I want the search term to be fetched from the api,i tried to use compontdidMount and conditionally fetch from the api but it didn't work as well.please help

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios';
class New extends Component {
    state = {
        term:'',
        res:[]
      }
      handleChange = e => {
        this.setState({ term: e.target.value });
      };
      handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = `https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=${this.state.term}`;
  var options = { 
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      "Accept" : "application/json" 
    }
  };
  axios.get(url,options)
        .then(response =>
          this.setState({res:[response.data.results]})
         
        )
        .catch(error => {
          // error.message is the error message
        })
        console.log(this.state)
      };
    render() { 
        return (<form className="jokes" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          value={this.state.title}
          type="text"
          name="term"
          required
          placeholder="cemetery"
        />
        <button type="submit"  value="Search" >Search</button>
        
      </form>  );
    }
}
 
export default New;
```

Comment: @RodrigoAmaral but i'm getting the data when i console.log(response) try this https://icanhazdadjoke.com/search?term=seagulls or cemetery as the term

Comment: Sorry, I erased my comment because it was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though the state does get updated correctly. [Check out this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stack-overflow-dad-joke-42pwt?file=/src/App.js) where I demo your code and render the API results.

Comment: @CosmicCallisto I've updated the answer. Everything seems OK to me. I think you add your `console.log` statement in the wrong place which gave you the false impression that state was not being updated.

Comment: I spent 8 hours on this : ( .Nobody told me this also happens...Thank You so much .. : )

Answer (score 2):

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-browser-vkz0r?file=/src/App.js), provided that you search a joke term that exists.

Just two observations:

1. Setting the state like this `this.setState({res:[response.data.results]})` will make the response be inside an array with only the zeroth element. But `response.data.results` is already an array, so just save `this.setState({res:response.data.results})`
2. `this.setState` does not take effect right away and logging in the next line won't work. The state change is queued and async... you are asking React to update when it can.

**EDIT:**

setState has a secondary and optional callback argument, that executes after the actual update:

```
this.setState({ res: [response.data.results] }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.res);
})
```

Comment: ..Thanks..Will the use async await help me avoid these kind of errors?

Comment: I updated my answer. You can also always log the props/state in the render method for debugging purposes or, even better, use React Dev Tools to check it.

Comment: thanks..once again..I was using redux and react Dev tools but i messed up the code midway so i thought using local state instead of store would save some time but it backfired..thank you for this valuable info : )

Comment: You welcome. BTW, for the record console.log might as well be async in the behaviour. I've noticed it's unreliable in some cases, don't count on it.

Comment: : |     won't use console.log anymore

Comment: Console logging is still the fastest way to quickly debug simple issues, with occasional "race conditions" in rare cases https://stackoverflow.com/q/23392111/6281832 . But don't let it make you forget about Devtools.